# How to check which character sets (codepages) font supports (has letters for)?

Tags: delphi, fonts, character, delphi-xe2

For my app I need to show a list of system fonts, but filter out all the fonts that do not support 20 predefined languages (the set is hardcoded) and show only those which do.

I can have a list of available fonts by calling `Vcl.Forms.Screen.Fonts`.
Knowing just the font name from that list, how do I check which character sets (codepages) this font supports (has actual letters for) ?

For example, common fonts like Arial or Times New Roman have characters for almost all European languages, including Cyrillic (and also Chinese and such). Yet many less common fonts often have only English letters.

The app is for internal use, so having a function that simply queries the font if it has a certain letter specific to some character set / codepage (e.g. `Ф` or `Ў` or `ξ`) and that it is not substituted with letter from another generic font (or some placeholder) would suffice.

Comment: The problem is, one can't be sure. A font may have all kinds of glyphs, just the one you need the most is missing. So IMHO this really needs to be tested char by char. The only thing I could find so far is [ScriptGetCMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd319122(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm not sure if that is what you want to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [GetGlyphIndices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144890(v=vs.85).aspx) function can be used to determine whether a glyph exists in a font.

### Citing the MSDN docs:

> ```
> DWORD GetGlyphIndices(
>   _In_  HDC     hdc,
>   _In_  LPCTSTR lpstr,
>   _In_  int     c,
>   _Out_ LPWORD  pgi,
>   _In_  DWORD   fl
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters [...]
>
> `fl` [in]: Specifies how glyphs should be handled if they are not
>                supported. This parameter can be the following value.
>
> **`GGI_MARK_NONEXISTING_GLYPHS`  --  Marks unsupported glyphs with the hexadecimal value 0xffff.**

The **Remarks** sections links again to the Uniscribe functions, e.g. [ScriptGetCMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd319122(v=vs.85).aspx)

> This function attempts to identify a single-glyph representation for each character in the string pointed to by lpstr. While this is useful for certain low-level purposes (such as manipulating font files), higher-level applications that wish to map a string to glyphs will typically wish to use the Uniscribe functions.

As both APIs are supported from Win2k onwards, it is probably a matter of taste which one to use.

(EDIT: Just noticed that the import is already in Windows.pas)

### Sample code

```
procedure Test( dc : HDC);
var str : UnicodeString;
    buf : array of WORD;
    len,i : Integer;
    count : DWORD;
begin
  str := 'abc'+WideChar($0416)+'äöü';
  len := Length(str);
  SetLength( buf, len);
  count := GetGlyphIndicesW( dc, PWideChar(str), len, @buf[0], GGI_MARK_NONEXISTING_GLYPHS);
  if count > 0 then begin
    for i := 0 to count-1 do begin
      Write('index ',i,': ');
      if buf[i] = $FFFF
      then Writeln('glyph missing')
      else Writeln('ok');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

yields

```
index 0: ok
index 1: ok
index 2: ok
index 3: glyph missing
index 4: ok
index 5: ok
index 6: ok
```

Comment: You are leaking the `HDC` that `GetDC(0)` returns. You need to release it when done using it. `dc := GetDC(0); GetGlyphIndicesW(dc,...); ReleaseDC(0, dc);`

Comment: Not anymore. It's a sample. Who cares.

Comment: @JensG I would also add that DC needs to have the font assigned, then it works for that font. Otherwise the code sample is a bit misleading - checking if DC has characters and not using font name anywhere ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check entire character set support, you can use [`EnumFontFamiliesEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows API - this doesn't let you query a single font, but rather returns a list of installed fonts which support a given character set (or which have any other set of queryable features).

You'll need a callback function [of the appropriate type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
function EnumFontCallback(lpelfe : PLogFont;
                          lpntme : PNewTextMetricEX;
                          FontType : DWORD;
                          lp : LPARAM) : integer; stdcall;
begin
  TMemo(lp).Lines.Add(lpelfe^.lfFaceName);
  result := 1;  // return zero to end enumeration
end;
```

And then call as :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lf : TLogFont;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lf,SizeOf(TLogFont));

  lf.lfCharSet := CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET;

  if not EnumFontFamiliesEx(Canvas.Handle,      // HDC
                            lf,                 // TLogFont
                            @EnumFontCallback,  // Callback Pointer
                            NativeInt(Memo1),   // user supplied pointer
                            0) then             // must be zero
  begin
    // function call failed.
  end;
end;
```

With the various fields in the [TLogFont (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure you can query a wide variety of font features.  In this case I have restricted only the character set (to Chinese Big-5 in the above example).

The callback will fire once for every resulting font returned from the query.  You will need to manage collecting this information as it is returned.  To add restrictions for several character sets you would need to call `EnumFontFamiliesEx` once for each character set of interest.  The following constants are defined in the RTL Windows unit :

```
ANSI_CHARSET
BALTIC_CHARSET
CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET
DEFAULT_CHARSET      // depends on system locale
EASTEUROPE_CHARSET
GB2312_CHARSET
GREEK_CHARSET
HANGUL_CHARSET
MAC_CHARSET
OEM_CHARSET          // depends on OS
RUSSIAN_CHARSET
SHIFTJIS_CHARSET
SYMBOL_CHARSET
TURKISH_CHARSET
VIETNAMESE_CHARSET
JOHAB_CHARSET
ARABIC_CHARSET
HEBREW_CHARSET
THAI_CHARSET
```

Cross-referencing would then be up to you - a `TDictionary` seems like a sensible tool to manage that task.