# Assigning hdc value to call GetGlyphIndices(hdc,lpstr,c,pgi,l) function n Delphi

Tags: delphi, fonts, gdi

There is a sample code in  [How to check which character sets (codepages) font supports (has letters for)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112144/how-to-check-which-character-sets-codepages-font-supports-has-letters-for) on getting characters sets using GetGlyphIndices function, but it does not say anything how to call it, particularly how to assign a font to dc. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VCL, the `TCanvas.Handle` is the HDC of the canvas.

For instance, a `TBitmap` has `Canvas.Handle`. Your main form also has a `Canvas.Handle`.

```
var
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bm.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Segoe UI';
    // Now you can use bm.Canvas.Handle as your HDC value
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;
```

or

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Segoe UI';
  // Canvas.Handle is your HDC
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. 
In the first example, I get an error at "bm.Font.Name := 'Segoe UI'", saying that the font is an undecleared identifier, in the second example calling GetGlyphIndicesW(Canvas.Handle, ....) rises error "EInOutError with message 'I/O error 105'". Can you help to resolve those problems?

Comment: @Rati2019: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot the `Canvas` (didn't test the code). It should be `bm.Canvas.Font.Name`, of course. The other issue I cannot help you with unless I have access to the full code you are using. (The error message you quote is highly unexpected in this case.)

Comment: I see that the linked A uses `Write` and `Writeln`. Are you perhaps using those procedures? They can only be used in console applications (or when you use legacy Pascal I/O). They cannot be used in a GUI application (unless you use legacy Pascal I/O). I suspect that is your problem. But of course you don't need them; they are only used for quick and dirty output/testing. You can use `ShowMessage` instead.

Comment: @Rati2019: Great! :)